# Identify in a pandas series when the trend changes from positive to negative

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series

I have a pandas dataframe with securities prices and several moving average trend lines of various moving average lengths. The data frames are sufficiently large that I would like to identify the most efficient way to capture the index of a particular series where the slope changes (In this example, let's just say from positive to negative for a given series in the dataframe.)

My hack seems very "hacky". I am currently doing the following (Note, imagine this is for a single moving average series):

```py
filter = (df.diff()>0).diff().dropna(axis=0)
new_df = df[filter].dropna(axis=0)
```

Full example code below:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

# Create a sample Dataframe
date_today = datetime.now()
days = pd.date_range(date_today, date_today + timedelta(7), freq='D')
close = pd.Series([1,2,3,4,2,1,4,3])
df = pd.DataFrame({"date":days, "prices":close})
df.set_index("date", inplace=True)
print("Original DF")
print(df)

# Long Explanation
updays = (df.diff()>0) # Show True for all updays false for all downdays
print("Updays df is")
print(updays)
reversal_df = (updays.diff()) # this will only show change days as True
reversal_df.dropna(axis=0, inplace=True) # Handle the first day
trade_df = df[reversal_df].dropna() # Select only the days where the trend reversed
print("These are the days where the trend reverses it self from negative to positive or vice versa ")
print(trade_df)

# Simplified below by combining the above into two lines
filter = (df.diff()>0).diff().dropna(axis=0)
new_df = df[filter].dropna(axis=0)
print("The final result is this: ")
print(new_df)
```

Any help here would be appreciated. Note, I'm more interested in balancing efficiencies between how best to do this so I can understand it, and how to make it sufficiently quick to compute.

Comment: Do you need to spot when slopes of moving averages change of sign or only changes in magnitude?

Comment: @MarcelloChiuminatto In this instance I was looking for them as they changed sign.

Answer (score 0):

Multiple moving average solution.

Look for the comment # *** THE SOLUTION BEGINS HERE *** to see the solution, before that is just generating data, printing and plotting to validate.

What I do here is to calculate the sign of MVA slopes so a positive slope will have a value of 1 and a negative slope a value of -1.

- Slope_i = MVA(i, ask; periods) - MVA(i, ask; periods)
- m<periods>_slp_sgn_i = Sign(Slope_i)

Then to spot slope changes I Calculate:

- m<periods>*slp_chg* = sign(m<periods>_slp_sgn_i - m<periods>_slp_sgn_i-1)

So for example if the slope changes from 1 (positive) to -1 (negative):

- sign (-1 - 1) = sign(-2) = -1

In the other hand, if the changes from -1 to 1:

- sign (1 - - 1) = sign(2) = 1

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

# GENERATE DATA RANDOM PRICE

_periods = 1000
_value_0 = 1.1300
_std = 0.0005
_freq = '5T'
_output_col = 'ask'

_last_date = pd.to_datetime('2021-12-15')
_p_t = np.zeros(_periods)
_wn = np.random.normal(loc=0, scale=_std, size=_periods)
_p_t[0] = _value_0
_wn[0] = 0
_date_index = pd.date_range(end=_last_date, periods=_periods, freq=_freq)
df= pd.DataFrame(np.stack([_p_t, _wn], axis=1), columns=[_output_col, "wn"], index=_date_index)

for i in range(1, _periods):
    df.iloc[i][_output_col] = df.iloc[i - 1][_output_col] + df.iloc[i].wn

print(df.head(5))

# CALCULATE MOVING AVERAGES (3)

df['mva_25'] = df['ask'].rolling(25).mean()
df['mva_50'] = df['ask'].rolling(50).mean()
df['mva_100'] = df['ask'].rolling(100).mean()

# plot to check 

df['ask'].plot(figsize=(15,5))
df['mva_25'].plot(figsize=(15,5))
df['mva_50'].plot(figsize=(15,5))
df['mva_100'].plot(figsize=(15,5))
plt.show()

# *** THE SOLUTION BEGINS HERE ***

# calculate mva slopes directions
# positive slope: 1, negative slope -1
df['m25_slp_sgn'] = np.sign(df['mva_25'] - df['mva_25'].shift(1))
df['m50_slp_sgn'] = np.sign(df['mva_50'] - df['mva_50'].shift(1))
df['m100_slp_sgn'] = np.sign(df['mva_100'] - df['mva_100'].shift(1))


# CALCULATE CHANGE IN SLOPE

# from 1 to -1: -1
# from -1 to 1: 1

df['m25_slp_chg'] = np.sign(df['m25_slp_sgn'] - df['m25_slp_sgn'].shift(1))
df['m50_slp_chg'] = np.sign(df['m50_slp_sgn'] - df['m50_slp_sgn'].shift(1))
df['m100_slp_chg'] = np.sign(df['m100_slp_sgn'] -  df['m100_slp_sgn'].shift(1))

# clean NAN
df.dropna(inplace=True)

# print data to visually check
print(df.iloc[20:40][['mva_25', 'm25_slp_sgn', 'm25_slp_chg']])

# query where slope of MVA25 changes from positive to negative
df[(df['m25_slp_chg'] == -1)].head(5)
```

WARNING: Data is generated random so you'll see the plots and the printings change each time you execute the code.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt answer @marcellochiuminatto.